# Flight transfer at Stansted Airport

Tags: short-connections, ryanair, stn, irish-citizens

My Ryanair flight from the Canary Islands lands at Stansted @ 15:30 on June 17. I am travelling on an Irish passport.

Would I make a flight to Cork @ 16.50?

Comment: Even if you would be able to make the flight in normal conditions, which I am not sure of at all, are you willing to take the risk of having to buy a new ticket on the day if your incoming flight is late?

Comment: You make a good point, I look at later flights

Comment: Do you travel with checked luggage?

Answer (score 2):

You might but [probably won't](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g1577375-i1410-k5303911-Ryanair_connection_flights_is_1h_enough-Stansted_Mountfitchet_Essex_England.html).